# Onestep checkout console : POST domain.com/rest/default/V1/rewards/mine/update 401

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, shipping-address

I am getting console errors in checkout page when i am filling shipping form :

```
POST https://www.domain.com/rest/default/V1/rewards/mine/update 401 (Unauthorized)
```

I am getting these errors mutiple time check this screeen : https://prnt.sc/sn6lnb

can anyone have any idea about this ?

Comment: Which magento version you are using?

Comment: @RahulBarot magento2.3.5p2